# Domain and Codomain after adding function

Tags: probability, functions

I have two functions $H_1,H_2:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and I want to define a new function $g(x)=H_1(x) + H_2(x)$. Would the domain and codomain off this function still be all the real numbers? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Domain of the sum of two functions is the intersection of the domains of each function, since $H_1(x)+H_2(x)$ only makes sense when both $H_1(x)$ and $H_2(x)$ are defined. In this case, the intersection of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb R$.

Both $H_1,H_2$ are real valued, so $H_1+H_2$ is also real valued. You can keep the codomain as $\Bbb R$ but remember that the codomain can also be a superset of $\Bbb R$ (or sometimes even a proper subset depending upon $H_1,H_2$) since a function does not need to attain all values in its codomain.